# Stop page execution like the alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I write `alert('Hello')`, the page execution stops and waits for approval to continue.

I have a  *div* setup to display as a fake alert, using HTML - this `div` has an 'OK' button.

I want the page to stop its execution (just like alert does) until the user click 'OK'.

Is it possible ?

Comment: It's possible with Promise API.

Comment: just what i looked for, sometime you need to stop it totally. i hope i doesn't use while loop :D i mean stopping the process without using any resource consuming code...

Comment: @Vixed: What's out of date about the current answers? That they don't mention promises? Or the upcoming await/async (the semantics of which are still not nailed down)?

Comment: must be another way @T.J.Crowder i need to **run code; --> custom alert --> break; go on;** can't write a callback anytime I need an alert.

Comment: @codef0rmer: *"It's possible with Promise API"* No, it isn't. Promises just let you write the callbacks differently, they don't let you stop the world like `alert` does. Promises are great, particularly when you need to compose or chain multiple promises, but they don't do what Royi asked for.

Comment: @Vixed: Sorry, you simply can't do that with JavaScript on a browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder **can't** is not in my dictionary.

Comment: @Vixed: `dictionary.add("can't")` then. :-) Just like you can't jump over the Eiffel tower completely unaided, you can't change the fundamental nature of how browers run JavaScript code. Async operations, and callbacks (boring old-fashioned ones or ones associated with promises), are (for now) a fundamental part of JavaScript code.

Comment: @Vixed Not possible to stop execution like an `alert`. `callback` is the only work around to go. The existing answer details this clearly and there simply isn't any other function like an alert in JavaScript.

Comment: @Vixed _"i need to run code; --> custom alert --> break; go on;"_ Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve? Do you mean break a loop?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't. Only the special built-ins can do that. For a while there was the [`showModalDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) special built-in that let you specify a URI for the content and thus customize it, but it was never widely supported and is now deprecated even by browsers that once supported it.

Instead, make your current alerting function that uses the `div` accept a callback for when the alert is closed (or return a promise that's settled when it's closed), to allow you to continue processing.

So for instance, if your code used to use `alert` and work like this:

```
function foo() {
    var x;

    x = doSomething();
    alert("Alert! Alert!");
    doSomethingAfterTheAlertIsCleared(x);
    doAnotherThingAfterward();
}
```

...you'd change it to:

```
function foo() {
    var x;

    x = doSomething();
    fakeAlert("Alert! Alert!", function() {
        doSomethingAfterTheAlertIsCleared(x);
        doAnotherThingAfterward();
    });
}
```

Note that now all the code that followed the alert is in a function, whose reference we pass into the `fakeAlert`. The `foo` function returns while the fake alert is still showing, but eventually the user dismisses the fake alert and our callback gets called. Note that our callback code has access to the locals in the call to `foo` that we were processing, because our callback is a closure (don't worry if that's a fairly new and/or mysterious term, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)).

Of course, if the only thing following the alert is a single function call that doesn't take any arguments, we could just pass that function reference directly. E.g., this:

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    alert("Alert! Alert!");
    doSomethingAfterTheAlertIsCleared();
}
```

becomes:

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    fakeAlert("Alert! Alert!", doSomethingAfterTheAlertIsCleared);
}
```

(Note that there are no `()` after `doSomethingAfterTheAlertIsCleared` -- we're *referring to the function object*, not calling the function; `fakeAlert` will call it.)

In case you're not sure how `fakeAlert` would call the callback, it would be within the event handler for the user "closing" the alert div, and you just call the argument for the callback just like you do with any other reference to a function. So if `fakeAlert` receives it as `callback`, you call it by saying `callback();`.

Comment: Just for fun I tried to 'hack' the alert/confirm dialogs and, even if I didn't succeed, I did notice that, in Chrome at least, one can check a box and prevent the window from creating additional modal dialogs. So even if somehow someone would replicate the same behaviour, it would still not be enough. This solution is the way to do it.

Comment: btw. you can stop `throw new FatalError("!! Stop JavaScript Execution !!");`

Comment: @johnSmith - That doesn't do what the OP is trying to do, it just terminates the function.

Comment: what's fakeAlert?

Comment: @ShivamSahil - It's the function that the OP would write to *"...make [their] current alerting function that uses the `div` accept a callback for when the alert is closed (or return a promise that's settled when it's closed), to allow [them] to continue processing."*

Answer (score 10):

**Yes it's possible**, i did inaccurate and not very well tested demo which does this.

Main concept:

1. in this example we have method Login.Try() which is executing
   Login.Proceed() method. Login.Proceed() makes AJAX query and we
   would like to wait for its execution, but don't want bind any
   handlers (just wait for it as window.alert() does)
2. instead of direct function's execution Login.Proceed, we use async()
   and await() methods (like in C#)
3. when we need to "pause" script and wait for something, we stop
   method execution using throw, and parse caller's function, to run
   its second part when waited (async) method has completed its
   execution.

What was left out of scope:

1. Clean code
2. Test solution for different browsers
3. Save/Restore local variables
4. Not works for loops.

Demo:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

Login.Try(); // START!! START!! START!!

var Login = {
    Url: "http://xxxx",
    Try: async(this, function (T) {

        console.log('before login');

        //var success = call(this, Login.Proceed); // normal call
        var success = await(this, Login.Proceed);  // that we want!

        console.log('after login');
        console.log('success ' + success);

    }),

    Proceed: function (callback) {
        console.log('before ajax');
        $.ajax({
            url: this.Url,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function () {
            console.log('after ajax');
            callback("role=admin");
        });
    }
}


function async(T, method){
   console.log('before async create');
   return function () { return method.apply(T); };
   console.log('after async create');
};

function await(T, method) {
    var fn = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
    var pos = fn.indexOf('await(');
    var allBeforeAwait = fn.substring(0, pos);

    var pos1 = fn.indexOf('await(');
    pos1 = fn.indexOf(',', pos1) + 1;
    var pos2 = fn.indexOf(')', pos1);
    var cc = fn.substring(pos1, pos2);


    pos = allBeforeAwait.lastIndexOf(';');
    var allBeforeCall = allBeforeAwait.substring(0, pos + 1) + "}";
    var callResult = allBeforeAwait.substring(pos + 1);

    var result = 10;
    var allAfterCall = "("+fn.substring(0, fn.indexOf(")")) + ",V){" + callResult + "V;";
    pos = fn.indexOf(')', pos) + 2;
    allAfterCall = allAfterCall + fn.substring(pos)+")";

    //uncomment to see function's parts after split
    //console.debug(allBeforeCall);
    //console.debug(cc);
    //console.debug(allAfterCall);

    method.apply(T, [function (value) {
        console.log('ajax response ' + value);
        eval(allAfterCall).apply(T, [T, value]);
    } ]);

    throw "";
};

</script>
```

Hope this demo will inspire you with some ideas.

Also, you can take a look on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbuckton/archive/2011/08/15/promise-js-2-0-promise-framework-for-javascript.aspx

Comment: Can you please upload jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sure - http://jsfiddle.net/vmysla/g3MzL/ Feel free to play with it. Script logs into browser's console most of actions

Comment: fiddle throw errors on chrome, i didn't test other browsers... console log: before ajax
(index):108 Uncaught await @ (index):108(anonymous function) @ (index):52(anonymous function) @ (index):74onclick @ (index):118
(index):65 after ajax
(index):104 ajax response role=admin
VM498:4 after login
VM498:5 success role=admin

Comment: hi @deadManN, thanks! I fixed that error. try now. you can open the console and see what happens

Comment: my whole os crashed, if i remind it, and i had nothing to do, sure i'll check, thanks

Comment: I like the approach, yet somehow having a script processor implemented in Javascript feels like overkill just for this. What I would see as a working solution - regardless of how complicated it would be - is to implement it as a script type, something like script type="text/fixeruper" and then a separate processor translate it into Javascript. See here: http://james.padolsey.com/cool-stuff/custom-javascript-with-parsescripts/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to pause execution for long period of time.

> function PauseExcecution() 
>   {
>     //Do some stuff
>     sleep(1000);
>    //Do some stuff...
>
> }
>
> ```
> function sleep(milliseconds) {
>   var start = new Date().getTime();
>   for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
>     if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
>       break;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: You could also use Infinity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible like the alert, but you can make things to look like an alert.

For example you make a function which calls functions. :) Then you make a function with a huge IF.

```
window.callfunction = function (f, a, b) /* function name, arguments, boolean*/
{
    var handler = window[f];
    if (typeof handler === 'function') {
        handler(a, b);
    } else {
        alert("No function like that mate, sry.");
    }
}

function deleteAfterConfirm(a, b) /* arguments, boolean */
{
    if (b == true) {
        alert("i can delete, confirmed.");
        alert(a);
        return false;
    }
    magicConfirm(a);
}

function magicConfirm(a) {
    /** 
        modals, popovers, etc, anything you want,
    **/
    $("#confirmModal").modal("show");
    /**
        and put the function's name to the binding element's data
    **/
    $("#returntrue").data("call", arguments.callee.caller.name);
    $("#returntrue").data("arguments", a);
    /** 
        the element like OK button in the alert 
        calls the magicConfirm function's caller function 
        with true, which is the deleteAfterConfirm, and 
        because the bool is true, it will alert i can delete... 
    **/
    $("#returntrue").bind("click", function () {
        callfunction($(this).data("call"), $(this).data("arguments"), true);
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#deleteAfterConfirm").on("click", function () {
        deleteAfterConfirm("variable which is needed later.");
    });
});
```

So now you can use the deleteAfterConfirm function like a function with alert() or confirm(), because it's recalling the other part if itself.

Not the best method, but this can somehow replace the confirms and alerts for a better looking version.
This is a way of the fake alertism :)

Have fun - R

Comment: This doesn't stop the execution of Javascript until `alert` is called.

Answer (score 0):

**You can** do it with Promise API. This is just about dividing your code and placing some lines in an action listener. Here is the sample code:

In this example, there are two buttons. Clicking first button starts a code and the rest of your code will be placed on `promise.then` function.

**Html Code:**

```
<body>
  <button id='startButton' onclick='start();'>Start Button</button>
  <button id='targetButton'>Target Button</button>
</body>
```

**Script Code:**

```
<script>
    function start(){
      console.log('first log'); //put your div displayer code here
      let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          console.log('promise started');
          let targetButton = document.getElementById('targetButton');
          targetButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
            resolve();
          });
      });
      promise.then(function() {
          console.log('second log'); //put the rest of your code
      });
    }
</script>
```

You will see `first log` and `promise started` just after triggering start button. `second log` will be displayed after you click the target button.

**The resources for Promise API:**

- [MDN: Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [MSDN: Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802826(v=vs.94).aspx)
- [A very detailed tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Comment: This doesn't stop the execution of Javascript the way `alert` does.

Comment: @Flimm, that's impossible. as accepted answer described. This answer shows a way to stop the flow and resume it whenever a user action happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the dialog box to close, the "open" property indicates whether the dialog box is open or closed. When it's done, resolve the promise. For synchronization, add a timer to periodically test this property.

```
    let d = document.querySelector('dialog')
    d.showModal()
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let timer = setInterval(_ => {
            if (!d.open) {
                resolve()
                clearInterval(timer)
            }
        }, 500)
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is possible using basic JavaScript. You could have the fake button set like this:

```
<button id="fakeButton" value="not" onclick="fakeButtonValChange()">OK</button>
```

Then:

```
function fakeButtonValChange() {
var fakebuttonval = document.getElementById("fakeButton").value;
document.getElementById("fakebutton").value = 
"clicked"
if (fakebuttonval == "clicked") {
*place stuff to show div here (i'm not good with css and that stuff)*
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Bootstap' modal

Then remove close button and disable model window hide by using below code

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

Bind your function and close event to OK button of that modal window.