# What methods are blocking in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blocking, synchronous

I'm trying to override the standard `confirm()` method in Javascript (make a nice UI and stuff). I've read a 100 posts that it "can't be done", but I don't want to give up until I have given it a fair shot. :)

So, the real problem is of course that the `confirm()` method must block all javascript execution until the user selects an option. So, what are the methods in Javascript that have blocking behavior? I've been able to come up with 5:

- `alert()` - does not suit me, because it displays an unwanted UI of its own;
- `confirm()` - the same problem as `alert()`;
- infinite loop - even modern browsers will eat away CPU like crazy and display a "stop javascript?" prompt after a few seconds;
- `XmlHttpRequest` in synchronous mode - sort of, but it involves server...
- `showModalDialog()` - nice, but I need a specific design, plus there are some browser compatibility requirements...

The best approach I have so far is to create an `<iframe>` with the prompt (which then gets its own javascript execution thread) and block with `XmlHttpRequest` until the user has selected an option in the `<iframe>`. Unfortunately this involves passing the result forth and back between the server, and I'd like to make this 100% client-side. Also, it ties up a server thread while the dialog is opened, and there might be some browser-specific ajax-timeouts that apply.

Can anyone think of any other Javascript methods that block execution which might be (ab)used to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The problem isn't really blocking, as that can be done with a while loop or something similar, but how do you intend to build a dialog that requires javascript when the user responds, but at the same time block execution of javascript. The better approach would be to build in a callback in your custom dialog, and then execute the rest of the code in the callback instead of relying on blocking.

Comment: Just switch from linear code design to a html popup and callback design, easy, did it several times already.

Comment: @adeneo - yes, that *would* be the best way, if there wasn't already a heap of code that must now be converted, including a 3rd party library. As for blocking-yet-not-blocking - that's solved by an `<iframe>` in any case.

Comment: If you want to block the execution in the main window, you can use [`showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog), though it's not working correctly in Chrome (yet).

Comment: @Teemu - Ahh, thanks, I forgot that. Unfortunately, that forces me to use a different UI that I need to. :(

Comment: A solution has been proposed on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758230/107510).

Answer (score 5):

No, **it can't be done** for a good reason. The arbitrary, custom-styled user interaction *in the page* is always asynchronous (event-based), and therefore does not work with any type of blocking behaviour (the event that would stop the infinite loop would only occur after the infinite loop has finished).

All those blocking methods that you mentioned do their user interaction in a different environment than the page - the `alert`/`confirm`/`prompt` popups controlled by the browser, the different page loaded by the `showModalDialog` - and that environment would need be able to gain focus while the first is frozen.

Creating a setup like this reliable is difficult enough. However, you could try almost *every* javascript functionality (that does not involve async callbacks), as all JS operations are synchronous by default. If you want to further experiment, I would suggest to look at those methods that deal with different DOM environments (`window.open`, `document.write`, `iframe.contentWindow` cross-frame-access) to see whether you can get any of these to spawn a second environment which *runs in parallel* reliably.