# Javascript Game: How to "suspend" a while loop to wait for a user input

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm writing a text-based game in javascript, and one of the main "features" is a input box which accepts a user input, and submits the input by a button tag. In my main game loop a call the button's onclick:

```
var game_u = new game_util();

                function Game_Main(){
                    while(active){
                        input = game_u.getText();
                        //p = new player();
                        active = false;
                    }
                }

                function game_util(){
                    this.getText = function(){
                        //The Submit button 
                        confirm_plr.onclick = function(){
                            //Input value
                            return player_in.value;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem with this way, though is that the while loop does not "wait" for the submit button to be clicked to get the input from the `game_u.getText(); function and continues on with the loop.

Is there a better way for me to do this, it is my first wack at a text-based game? I don't want to use the prompt method, because it breaks the immersion of the gameplay.

I'm also coming from Java, an object-oriented programming language, so that's why I use a while loop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a `prompt` box, like an `alert` will pause execution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in Javascript - delay between actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Comment: Move game_u.getText() into a global variable when the button is clicked, and then "consume" this in the game loop by setting it back to blank when done reading it during one iteration of the game loop.  That's one possibility.  Note: persistent javascript loops are a bit unusual.

Comment: you might want to look at using callbacks

Comment: Here's a few ways to get around the current lack of "await" in javascript...https://thomashunter.name/blog/the-long-road-to-asyncawait-in-javascript/

Comment: You should not be using that `while` loop here in the first place – but rather embrace the fact that JavaScript is an event-driven language.

Comment: @ebyrob But the button click will never occur ...

Comment: Second for callbacks.  You should pop the dialog to get input from the user - and set event handlers for the submit from that dialog.  I would seriously reconsider the structure of your application as you are going to run into a lot of problems if it's entirely loop-driven.

Comment: If I shouldn't be using a while loop, what would replace it?

Comment: I will look into callbacks, thank you.

Comment: without knowing what you're trying to do, that's impossible to answer.  But it should be event driven.  User actions should trigger the execution of functions that interpret their input and update the display and/or prompt the user for more input.  I don't understand why you have a while loop or what its purpose is, though, so like I said it's impossible to answer that question.

Comment: I came from Java so I have a Java mindset, that's why I used a while loop.

Comment: @TheRailsRouter See my updated answer. Use an event listener.

Comment: Your while loop should be providing some functionality that you couldn't easily get elsewhere.  If you don't know why it's there, it's probably safe bet that it should be replaced.  A loop is typically used when you want to continue executing a process until some condition is met (1000 iterations, or until a sum exceeds a threshold, etc.).

Comment: Also, OOP languages don't necessitate the use of while loops.  Objectives do.  I code almost entirely in C#/JS/SQL and I couldn't tell you the last time I needed a while loop.  Out of curiosity, why do you think that your Java experience means that you should use while loops?

Comment: It's just the way I learned it, while loops certainly aren't necessary, I was just taught this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to suspend with user input, a simple `prompt()` box will do.

Try this:

```
var input = prompt("Enter data here", "");
```

This will wait for input and store it into variable `input`.

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/spjs8spp/) on JSFiddle.net.

---

AFAIK, synchronous JS is not possible, as according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509296/wait-for-a-user-event):

> JavaScript is asynchronous, you cannot "pauses" execution. Moreover, while javascript is running the entire user interface freezes, so the user cannot click the button.

As to your question,

> If I shouldn't be using a while loop, what would replace it?

because JS is event driven, and you're trying to run code every time that button is clicked (and input is entered), just use a `onclick` handler.

So, rather than this:

```
while(active) {
    input = game_u.getText();
    p = new player();
    active = false;
}
```

You can do:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    input = game_u.getText();
    p = new player();
    active = false;
});
```

This will run the code every time the button is clicked, essentially the same as what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the prompt method, since it breaks the immersion of my game. A white pop-up box is not what I'm trying to do, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to break the different stages of your game into functions corresponding to the different stages (rooms, levels etc.) which are called depending on the user's input; you will also need a variable that saves the game's current state (`room` in the example below).

```js
(function Game() {
    var room = 1;
    document.getElementById('playerSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var playerInput = document.getElementById('playerInput').value;
        if (playerInput == "Go to room 2") {
            room = 2;
        }
        if (playerInput == "Go to room 1") {
            room = 1;
        }
        if (room == 1) {
            room1(playerInput);
        } else if (room == 2) {
            room2(playerInput);
        }
        document.getElementById('playerInput').value = '';
    });
    function room1(playerInput) {
        output('You are in the first room and entered the command ' + playerInput);
    }
    function room2(playerInput) {
        output("Now you're in room 2. Your command was " + playerInput);
    }
    function output(text) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<p>' + text + '</p>';
    }       
})();
```

```css
#output {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
label {
    display: block; margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<label for="playerInput">Player input</label>
<input id="playerInput" type="text" size=50 />
<input id="playerSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spjs8spp/2/

Comment: I'm having so much fun playing this makeshift game =) +1

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten some great info in the commentary. An evented model might be ideal, but you can do persistent loops. I'm not as familiar with it, but HTML5 Canvas is just that. Maybe look into that some, since nobody else mentioned it yet.