# Javascript Alerts and Prompts

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, alert, prompt

I have looked around alot to find a custom prompt that will suit my purposes but am coming across a fundamental problem in most of them.  I have alot of iterative JSP includes and I want to pause the execution of the web page while waiting for a response I can do this with the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//...
var prompt = prompt('Hello There', 'Hello Back');
var test = 5;

</script>
```

In this code test will not become 5 until you click ok on the prompt, but in most custom prompts I have seen test will become 5 immediately.  I understand that there are complicated ways around this by modularizing code and using setTimeouts() what I am looking for though is one of two things.  Is there a way to halt all execution until a dialog box is closed or is there a way to custom skin a java script alert/prompt/confirm.

Comment: the question has been answered but to avoid confusion for other readers custom meaning non native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to halt all execution until a dialog box is closed

That's what you get when using `alert`, `confirm` or `prompt`. Those are modal windows and block the execution flow.

There are no other ways to block the flow like that, see here: [Stop page execution like the alert() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807799/stop-page-execution-like-the-alert-function)

> or is there a way to custom skin a java script alert/prompt/confirm.

No, there isn't any way to customize the native alert boxes.

> I understand that there are complicated ways around this by modularizing code

This is the only solution if you want an alert box that is both blocking, and uses a "custom skin". You should use callbacks.