# function logic for stopping game and checking/displaying winner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on this tic tac toe game for a while, I've been held up on this one problem with the logic in the `checkForWin()` function. This function checks each possible winning combination just fine, but there's a lag in the `alert('game over')` message that is suppose to fire as soon as a winning combo is matched. 
  Here's the funny part, when you're about to click on that square to win the game, `alert()` fires before `square.innerHTML = x` or o. and if you look at my code the first thing to happen if the game isn't already over or if the square isn't empty is `this.innerHTML = playerTurn;`  then `checkForWin();`
  Anyway to get around this I've had to `setTimeout(checkForWin, 1000)` to delay that alert message 1s after the winning move is clicked. And here's the main problem, `setTimeout` didn't help me, now when you click that winning move nothing happens!!! now turn has switched and if the other player goes after the the previous turn and move has already won, that is when `alert('Game Over');`

```js
const winCombos = [
     [0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8],
     [0, 3, 6],
     [1, 4, 7],
     [2, 5, 8],
     [0, 4, 8],
     [6, 4, 2]
];

let playerTurn = 'x';
let gameEnded = false;
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
     cells[i].addEventListener('click', runGame);
}

function runGame() {
     if(gameEnded===true||this.innerHTML!=='') {
          return;
     }
     this.innerHTML = playerTurn;
     setTimeout(checkForWin, 1000);
     switchTurn();
}

function checkForWin() {
     for(let i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
          const c0 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][0]);
          const c1 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][1]);
          const c2 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][2]);

          if(c0.innerHTML===playerTurn&&c1.innerHTML===playerTurn&&c2.innerHTML===playerTurn) {
               gameEnded = true;
               alert('Game Over');
          }
     }
}

function switchTurn() {
     if(playerTurn === 'x') {
          playerTurn = 'o'
     } else if(playerTurn === 'o') {
          playerTurn = 'x';
     }
}
```

```css
td {
 border:  2px solid #333;
 height:  100px;
 width:  100px;
 text-align:  center;
 vertical-align:  middle;
 font-family:  "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font-size:  70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -155px;
 top: 220px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
 border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tic tac toe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c0"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c1"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c3"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c4"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c6"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c7"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c8"></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="endgame">
   <div class="text">Cant see this text</div>
  </div>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807799/stop-page-execution-like-the-alert-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you could do is, instead of calling `setInterval` on your `checkForWin` function, just edit the inside of your `checkForWin` function:

```
if (c0.innerHTML===playerTurn&&c1.innerHTML===playerTurn&&c2.innerHTML===playerTurn) {
    gameEnded = true;
    setInterval(function() {
        alert('Game Over');
    }, 1000);
}
```

And just change this line inside `runGame` from this:

```
setTimeout(checkForWin, 1000);
```

to this:

```
checkForWin();
```

Also, why do you have the `else if` conditional at the bottom of your `switchTurn` function? The `playerTurn` variable can only be `x` or `o`, can't it? Just use an `else` statement.